# "The totient is the discrete Fourier transform of the gcd, evaluated at 1."

Tags: fourier-transform, totient-function, fast-fourier-transform

I was looking at the Wikipedia page for the totient function and stumbled across this fact. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Fourier_transform)

> The totient is the discrete Fourier transform of the gcd, evaluated at 1.[16] Let
>
> $${\displaystyle {\mathcal {F}}\{\mathbf {x} \}[m]=\sum \limits _{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cdot e^{{-2\pi i}{\frac {mk}{n}}}}$$
> where $x_k = gcd(k,n$) for $k ∈ {1, ..., n}$. Then
>
> $${\displaystyle \varphi (n)={\mathcal {F}}\{\mathbf {x} \}[1]=\sum \limits _{k=1}^{n}\gcd(k,n)e^{-2\pi i{\frac {k}{n}}}.}$$

I tried reading the cited paper ([http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/i50/i50.pdf](http://math.colgate.edu/%7Eintegers/i50/i50.pdf)), but frankly I don't quite understand. Looking for a proof that is more clear, or at least indicates what topics I should look into to understand why this would be true.

Comment: First step is to show that if $p$ is a prime, so $\phi(p)=p-1$, then $$\sum_{k=1}^p\gcd(k,p)e^{-2\pi ik/p}=p-1$$ Can you do that?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The first p-1 terms are just the roots of unity other than 1, which must add up to -1, and the last term is just p*1, so adding them up gives p-1. Not sure where to go from there, though.

Comment: My first instinct is that it you can extend it by using the property that the totient function multiplies for relatively prime numbers + using some property of fourier transforms, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Maybe the next step, now that you have proved it for primes, is to prove it for prime powers.